# Where to place generated sources in order to make them visible for testCompile goal?

Tags: java, maven

[maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html) gets sources from `./src/test/java`. How can I instruct it to use sources from `./target/generated-sources/test` as well?

Maybe they should be placed somewhere else to become visible for `testCompile` goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the plugin generating these sources should configure the source folders for the compiler plugin. When these are not generated by a maven plugin, you can use the [build-helper plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to add additional folders. See the [second example here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/howto.html).